# How to loop a certain piece of a python script

Tags: python, loops, time

In this script, https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yhlOtEAcI4qCAzRam4hT5H3xgvQAonHG_k7QaJX2vVk/edit?usp=sharing , I made a weather data display. I want to know how to loop the code so that every 180 seconds it updates the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import time

def code():
    #Put all of your code here

while True:
    code()
    time.sleep(180)
```

This will run your code, then wait 3 minutes, and repeat infinitely.

Comment: But I include GPIO cleanup in the code, will it wait 180 seconds and then cleanup? Or will it cleanup right away and then wait 180.

Comment: It will cleanup and then wait 180. So you will need a `cleanup()` function, and do `code(); time.sleep(180); cleanup()`

Comment: So then that will make it wait display the LEDs for 3 minutes, cleanup, then repeat right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So then the code will be:     while True:     code()     time.sleep(180). GPIO.cleanup()

Comment: Sorry I am new to this python and I can't get this wrong

Comment: Yes that should work.